# Why isn't this ajax post working correctly?

Tags: javascript, ajax

The function below makes an AJAX post. makepostrequest is just a standard ajax post request function I wrote that I have omitted since it's not the source of the problem. The function below does not send 'widgets'.

```
function widgets_positions(){
    var widgets = '';
    var col_1 = document.getElementById('col_1');
    var col_2 = document.getElementById('col_2');
    var col_3 = document.getElementById('col_3');
    for(i = 0; i < col_1.childNodes.length; i++) {
        var str1 = col_1.childNodes[i].className;
        if(str1 && str1.match('widget')) widgets+='&c[1]['+i+']='+col_1.childNodes[i].id;
    }

makePOSTRequest('/ajax.php',"widgets="+widgets);


    return true;
}
```

BUT if in place of 'widgets' I try to post

```
var random = 'sumo'
makePOSTRequest('/ajax.php',"widgets="+random);
```

it works.

Not only that, if I place an echo command in the above before `'makepostrequest'`, `'widgets'` get printed out on the clinetside as `c[1]c[1]blahblah`.

So why does `var random = 'sumo'` get sent but the `'widgets'` variable does not?

Comment: If you're sure `widgets` contains a non-empty string, and a different string works, then the only options are a) your `makePOSTRequest` function is failing, or b) your server-side code isn't handling the querystring correctly. I don't think it's possible to debug without more code.

Comment: Could it be the leading ampersand? `widgets+='&c[1]['+i+']='+col_1.childNodes[i].id`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because 'widgets' starts with an &, which will mark the beginning of another variable definition in that request. So 'widgets' goes empty.

Try to remove that '&', and parse it accordingly in server-side to correctly read each widget.

Comment: Ahh! Thanks a million! I've been stuck on this for 2 days. That was the answer.

Answer (score 0):

May be it is cached? Clear browser cache and then if it works, add cache expiry in the ajax.php.

Answer (score 0):

```
widgets+='&c[1]['+i+']='+col_1.childNodes[i].id;
makePOSTRequest('/ajax.php',"widgets="+widgets);
```

So you're going to end up with the form-encoded string:

```
widgets=&c[1][0]=foo&c[1][1]=bar
```

That is, a `widgets` parameter with an empty string value, then a `c[1][0]` parameter with `foo` value, and so on. Is that what you wanted?

If you actually wanted to pack your whole `&c[1][0]=foo&c[1][1]=bar` string into the `widgets` parameter, the string you'd need would be:

```
widgets=%26c[1][0]=foo%26c[1][1]=bar
```

turning those ampersand separators into URL-encoded versions so they don't split the form data. To do that, you'd say:

```
makePOSTRequest('/ajax.php',"widgets="+encodeURIComponent(widgets));
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will look into that encodeURIComponent function, I haven't encountered it before.